# Test of statistical significance for equality of two ratios rather than proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, ratio, mortality

I have data from two sample surveys done on Maternal Mortality. At each survey, the number of live births and the number of maternal deaths have been recorded. I have calculated the Maternal Mortality Ratio (MMR) per 100K live births from each sample. Now, I would like to see whether the MMRs are statistically significantly different. Which statistical test should I use? Is the usual Z-test for proportions appropriate, given that it's a ratio, not a proportion and the numerator is not a part of the denominator?

Edit:
To further clarify, the null hypothesis is: the true MMR is the same for the two groups, and the alternate hypothesis is the true MMRs are different for the two groups.

Comment: (1) What exactly are your null & alternative hypotheses? (2) Presumably you say the numerator is not a part of the denominator because a mother may give birth to twins, triplets, &c. But are maternal deaths from still-births counted in the numerator?

Comment: (1) The null hypothesis is that the MMRs for two groups are equal, the alternate is that they are unequal. (2) Yes, maternal deaths due to stillbirths would be counted in the numerator.